# Patron de diseño Decorator

Tags: java, poo, clase, decoradores

Estoy entregando un trabajo en el que tengo que simular un juego de guerra entre diferentes personajes. Estas unidades son clases que heredan de una clase mas general llamada Unidad aca les dejo el codigo:

```
package unidades;


public abstract class Unidad {


    private Integer salud;
    private Double posx;
    private Double posy;
    private Double rangomax;
    private Double rangomin;


    Unidad(Double posx, Double posy, Integer salud, Double rangomax, Double rangomin){
        this.posx = posx;
        this.posy = posy;
        this.salud = salud;
        this.rangomax = rangomax;
        this.rangomin = rangomin;
    }



    public Integer getSalud() {
        return salud;
    }

    public void setSalud(Integer salud) {
        this.salud = salud;
    }

    public Double getPosx() {
        return posx;
    }

    public void setPosx(Double posx) {
        this.posx = posx;
    }

    public Double getPosy() {
        return posy;
    }

    public void setPosy(Double posy) {
        this.posy = posy;
    }

    public Double getRangomax() {
        return rangomax;
    }

    public void setRangomax(Double rangomax) {
        this.rangomax = rangomax;
    }

    public Double getRangomin() {
        return rangomin;
    }

    public void setRangomin(Double rangomin) {
        this.rangomin = rangomin;
    }

    @Override
    public abstract String toString();


    public Double calcularDistancia(Unidad victima) {
        Double resultado;
        resultado = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(victima.getPosx()-posx, 2) + Math.pow(victima.getPosy()-posy, 2));
        return resultado;
    }


    public boolean validarVida() {
        boolean validacion;
        if(getSalud()>=1) validacion = true;
        else validacion = false;
        return validacion;
    }


    public boolean validarRango(Unidad victima) {
        boolean validacion;
        if(calcularDistancia(victima)>=rangomin && calcularDistancia(victima)<=rangomax) validacion = true;
        else validacion = false;
        return validacion;
    }


    public abstract void infligirDaño(Unidad victima);


    public void atacarUnidad(Unidad victima) {/*template method**/
        if(validarVida()==true) {
            if(validarRango(victima)==true) {
                infligirDaño(victima);
            }else System.out.println("La unidad esta fuera de rango de ataque");
        } else System.out.println("No se puede atacar cuando la unidad esta muerta");
    }


}
```

les muestro el ejemplo de una subclase como por ejemplo Arquero:

```
package unidades;
import java.util.Random;

public class Arquero extends Unidad{


    private Integer daño = 5;
    private Integer flechas = 20;


    public Arquero(Double posx, Double posy){
        super(posx,posy,50,5.0,2.0);
    }


    public Integer getDaño() {
        return daño;
    }

    public void setDaño(Integer daño) {
        this.daño = daño;
    }

    public Integer getFlechas() {
        return flechas;
    }

    public void setFlechas(Integer flechas) {
        this.flechas = flechas;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String cadena;
        cadena = "Arquero:  Salud: " + getSalud() + "  Flechas: " + flechas + "\n";
        return cadena;
    }

    public void recargaFlechas() {
        int random;

        Random j = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        random = j.nextInt(10)+1;

        if(random > 9) {
            flechas = flechas +6;
            System.out.println("Carcaj recargado. flechas : " + flechas);       
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void infligirDaño(Unidad victima) {

            if(getFlechas()>=1) {
            victima.setSalud(victima.getSalud() - getDaño());
            setFlechas(getFlechas() - 1);
            }
            else System.out.println("No hay suficientes flechas");
            recargaFlechas();       
    }

    }
```

y otra subclase como lancero:

```
package unidades;

public class Lancero extends Unidad{
private Integer daño = 25;

public Lancero(Double posx, Double posy){
    super(posx,posy,150,3.0,1.0);
}

public Integer getDaño() {
    return daño;
}

public void setDaño(Integer daño) {
    this.daño = daño;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String cadena;
    cadena = "Lancero:  Salud: " + getSalud() + "\n";
    return cadena;
}

@Override 
public void infligirDaño(Unidad victima) {
    victima.setSalud(victima.getSalud() - getDaño());
}


}
```

y despues en un metodo main ejecuto algunas pruebas , algo sencillo como para comprobar las clases:

```
package principal;

import unidades.Arquero;
import unidades.Lancero;

import unidades.*;

public class Pruebas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Arquero a = new Arquero(1.00,1.00);
        Lancero l = new Lancero(3.00,3.00);
        Caballero c = new Caballero(3.00,4.00);
        Soldado s = new Soldado(3.00,3.00);

        l.atacarUnidad(a);
        a.atacarUnidad(l);


        System.out.println(l.toString() + a.toString());


        c.atacarUnidad(s);
        s.atacarUnidad(c);


        System.out.println(s.toString() + c.toString());


    }

}
```

el tema es cuando el trabajo me pide que implemente el patron decorator. Tengo que agregar 3 items que puedan ser equipados por una unidad , se puede equipar uno solo, dos, o todos.NO SON EXCLUYENTES. Uno da daño de ataque otro da defensa y otro aumenta la energia (esa es para una clase Soldado pero que no puse aca). La pregunta es , puedo usar el patron decorator para implementar esos items usando el codigo que acabo de pasar? gracias por leer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a simplificar tu problema. El ejercicio te indica que debes crear una Interfaz llamada "Unidad" y otra llamada "Item" las interfaces por lo que veo solo necesitan lo siguiente:

*Unidad*

```
public interface Unidad {
  public long getDaño();
}
```

*Item*

```
public interface Item {
  public long getDañoBase();
}
```

ahora las Unidades pueden utilizar Items que den un bonus de daños. Para que los items no sean excluyentes puedes utilizar varios patrones, el de composición o bien el decorador. Tu problema te solicita el decorador, así que creamos una clase, llamada: "UnidadConItem" dicha clase tiene la responsabilidad de relacionar los bonus de los Items con las Unidades.

```
public class UnidadConItem implements Unidad {
  private final Unidad unidad;
  private final Item item;

  public UnidadConItem(Unidad unidad, Item item)
  {
    this.unidad = unidad;
    this.item = item;
  }

  @Override
  public long getDaño()
  {
    return (unidad.getDaño() + item.getDañoBase());
  }
}
```

Ahora creas las clases de Unidades

*Arquero*

```
public class Arquero implements Unidad {
  @Override
  public long getDaño()
  {
    return 5;
  }
}
```

*Lancero*

```
public class Lancero implements Unidad {
  @Override
  public long getDaño()
  {
    return 25;
  }
}
```

Ahora creas las clases de Items y sus Bonus

*FlechasFuego*

```
public class FlechasFuego implements Item
{
  @Override
  public long getDañoBase()
  {
    return 100;
  }
}
```

*Excalibur*

```
public class Excalibur implements Item
{
  @Override
  public long getDañoBase()
  {
    return 50;
  }
}
```

*PocionConcentracion*

```
public class PocionConcentracion implements Item
{
  @Override
  public long getDañoBase()
  {
    return 10;
  }
}
```

*TalismanNegativo*

```
public class TalismanNegativo implements Item
{
  @Override
  public long getDañoBase()
  {
    return -30;
  }
}
```

Luego puedes manipular la vida de una Unidad y sus items;

```
Unidad pj = new Arquero(); // daño = 5
pj = new UnidadConItem(pj, new FlechasFuego()); // daño = 105
pj = new UnidadConItem(pj, new PocionConcentracion()); // daño = 115
pj = new UnidadConItem(pj, new TalismanNegativo()); // daño = 85
System.out.println(pj.getDaño()); // imprime "85"
```

Te dejo el código completo en el siguiente enlace:

https://mega.nz/#!Lwg01S4D!N6vdApPO8azHxZnzpoIZwB2tGqoeUaEoC9O4sRTTcwo

Comment: Joya, voy a intentar implementarlo, y no se puede dejar a la clase abstracta Unidad tal cual esta? porque en el ejemplo vos pones a Unidad como si fuera una interfaz

Comment: Lo definí como interfaz para dar más versatilidad. Recuerda que en POO solo puedes extender de una clase (no existe multi herencia) mientras que puedes implementar todas las interfaces que quieras. Ahora respondiendo a tu pregunta: sí puedes dejarlo como clase abstracta.